# How to use a Kendo grid with a column template

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm trying to place an action link into a grid cell according to [example here](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/configuration#razor):

```
columns.Template(@<text>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Home", new { id = p.ProductID })
</text>);
```

but have had no success.
It is not compiling because of errors in the sample. I tried to replace with:

```
columns.Template(p => @<text>
    @Html.ActionLink("LinkTitle", "Edit", "Home", new { id = p.ProductID })
</text>);
```

and got:

> CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new
>   object expressions can be used as a statement

Then I tried:

```
columns.Template(p => {
    Html.ActionLink("LinkTitle", "Edit", "Home", new
    {
        id = p.ProductID
    });
});
```

and got:

> System.NotSupportedException

So where can I find a **stable** and complete example of using column template with Kendo UI grid?

Comment: Did you try? `columns.Template(@<text>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Home", new { id = @item.ProductID })
</text>);`

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `item` in razor template delegates. It is the implicit variable name. Change your code to:

```
columns.Template(@<text>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Home", new { id = item.ProductID })
</text>);
```

The help topic you have linked to is wrong and will be fixed soon.

Comment: I should put my comment as answer ;).